# PostgreSQL search_path issue using pg_dump created plain .sql file

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, search-path

Created a Postgres plain text SQL file using `pg_dump`. When importing the text SQL file using the `psql -f` everything seems to be running fine.

But the newly imported databases is missing the `search_path`. The source database has the `search_path`, I expected the destination database to have the same. Looking at the plain SQL file in an editor I see the `SET search_path` command. So is this an issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `search_path` is set per session and can be changed any time. You can store presets for a database, a role or even a role in a particular database. That would be set with commands like:

```
ALTER DATABASE test SET search_path = blarg,public;
ALTER ROLE foo SET search_path = blarg,public;
```

Etc.

Or maybe you want a general setting in `postgresql.conf` to begin with? See link below.

A plain:

```
SET search_path = blarg,public;
```

like you see in SQL file only sets a `search_path` for the session it is executed in.

The underlying issue may be this ([quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/database-roles.html)):

> Database roles are global across a database cluster installation (and
>   **not per individual database**).

Bold emphasis mine.

A backup of a *database* with `pg_dump` (not the whole cluster with `pg_dumpall`, not including global objects), does not include roles. If you have set a default `search_path` for a role, then that is not included.

Details:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

Comment: My understanding is like the `search_pat`h that I see in the plain sql file is just for the database objects to be able to successfully import. That doesn't really set the `search_path` for the database even though the source database has the `search_path` set at the time of export.?

Comment: @varun7447: Like I said: a plain `SET` only sets the `search_path` for the current session.

Comment: Great., so I just trying to see if there is a better way to get every object and setting as is from source database the same in destination database. Including `search_path`.

Answer (score 1):

Setting of search_path does not appear in the pg_dump's output even if set on database level, ie. by command

```
ALTER DATABASE XXX set search_path to aaa, bbb, ccc;
```

Then, after dumping and restoring the database with pg_dump/pg_restore, the restored database does not have the search_path set, ie. the one coming from source template stays active in the restored database.

Tested with version 13.7.

It is also discussed here [PG-mail-list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAKFQuwag%3DYiKTCbVE85EvuBx5aVC06ctsjtgA6tU_6-V4stVfQ%40mail.gmail.com) and David J. explains it, but I consider it a bug in pg_dump (or better called: design flaw). All per-database settings should appear in the dump, imho.